# FFMPEG to add audio to video at specific intervals

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a audio of 2 mints . How to add it to a longer video of say 10 mints at some specific intervals using ffmpeg. Say after 2 mints of the audio play there is a 1 minute gap and then it plays again . I tried to add it but it plays only once at the start of the video

Comment: Try adding silence in the intervals - try using [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-apad) filter. For audio looping try using [aloop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aloop) filter.